# Running Firefox as a restricted user

Tags: sudo, firefox, x11

For security reasons, I would like to run Firefox under a different (underprivileged) account. I thought it would be as easy as setting up a user and then run with `gksudo`, but it appears that there is more to it. What am I doing wrong?

```
tkn@tkn-desktop-ubuntu $ sudo useradd tkn-firefox
tkn@tkn-desktop-ubuntu $ gksudo -u tkn-firefox firefox
No protocol specifiedError: cannot open display: :0.0
```

I'm guessing that the user doesn't get access to X11 for some reason, but shouldn't `gksudo` do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using '`xhost +`' is a bad habit to get into.  If you're having a problem with X11 and "can't open display ??:?", use `xauth` to exchange cookies and set the `DISPLAY` variable in the new environement.

In this case, I've had success on Ubuntu 9.04 getting `gksu` to do that heavy lifting. (It didn't work for me til I added the `--su-mode` )

```
$ gksu --su-mode -u tkn-firefox firefox
```

It does spit out a message about '`Warning: Tried to connect to session manager, None of the authentication protocols specified are supported`' but it appears to work otherwise.

Comment: Ooh, looks like fun. Will have to stop being a neanderthal and use that in future :)

Comment: You solved the issue I was having as well. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I find I have to do "xhost +" (if there are any more potential X clients on your network, be a bit more selective) and *don't* "su -", just "su". I have not really thought about why this might be, but it works OK for me.